# Google Tag Manager Cross Domain Tracking Javascript window.open

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

Cross-domain tracking works for this website on its normal html links except when the search function is used, which is submitted through a div tag with the class "do-book-now". The div tag does a search with the external javascript:

```
$(document.body).getElements('.do-book-now').addEvent('click', function(){
    var arr = document.id('datepick').get("value");
    var nts = document.id('n_nights').getSelected().get("value");
    var a = document.id('n_adults').getSelected().get("value");
    var c = document.id('n_children').getSelected().get("value");
    var url = 'https://www.externaldomain.com';
    if (arr != '') url += '&arr=' + arr;
    if (nts != 'Nights') url += '&nts=' + nts;
    if (a != 'Adults') url += '&a=' + a;
    if (c != 'Children') url += '&c=' + c;
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'gtm.external_search'}); // Google Tag Manager event
    window.open(url);
    document.id('book-now-details').toggle();
});
```

All referral information in analytics is lost once the user goes to this external domain which has the same GTM install. If cross-domain GTM is working for normal links, what else should I be doing to get it working in this situation?

You can see an event is fired, which works, so we can tell when the search occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the name of the event you are pushing to the dataLayer. There is no such event as `gtm.external_search`. If you want to use a custom event to track click events, drop `gtm.` from the custom event name.

Comment: It's just a custom event created with "gtm" in its name. The event is used to track form submits and at the moment, has nothing to do with the cross-domain tracking.

Comment: Do you get any error messages on the console? Do these events fire properly?

Comment: The gtm.external_search event fires. The only console error is "Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead." and this is with another javascript file by mootools.